# basic login functionality using keycloak in vue 3 application

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, keycloak

trying to achieve basic login functionality on click of the login button which redirects to the login page of the keycloak once the credentials are entered then store the access token and refresh token in the localstorage.

problem facing-
keycloak login with user creds is successfully
also redirecting back to the dashboard page is successful
**but not able to store the tokens in the local storage**
**also not able to logout on click of the logout button**

any insights regarding this flow?

getting error mentioned below-

> Uncaught runtime errors: ERROR adapter is undefined
> Keycloak/kc.logout@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/keycloak-js/dist/keycloak.mjs:433:5
> logoutWithKeyCloak@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/layouts/TheHeader.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:39:16
> render/<.default</_cache[1]@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/layouts/TheHeader.vue?vue&type=template&id=664910a2:24:95

```
<template>
  <nav class="bg-gray-darker">
    <LayoutContainer>
      <ul class="h-[50px] w-full flex justify-center">
        <li><button @click="loginWithKeyCloak"
            class="flex items-center h-full font-sans text-16 text-[#FFFFFF] whitespace-nowrap px-5"><b>Login</b></button>
        </li>
        <li><button @click="logoutWithKeyCloak"
            class="flex items-center h-full font-sans text-16 text-[#FFFFFF] whitespace-nowrap px-5"><b>Logout</b></button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </LayoutContainer>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
import LayoutContainer from '../components/LayoutContainer.vue'
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  url: 'http://localhost:8090/auth',
  realm: 'keycloak-demo',
  clientId: 'vue-test--app',
  onLoad: 'login-required'
})

export default {
  name: 'TheHeader',
  components: {
    LayoutContainer
  },
  mounted() {
  },
  methods: {
    loginWithKeyCloak() {
      keycloak
        .init({ onLoad: 'login-required' })
        .then((authenticated) => {
          console.log('User is authenticated =============', authenticated)
          if (!authenticated) {
            window.location.reload()
          } else {
            localStorage.setItem('vue-access-token', keycloak.token)
            localStorage.setItem('vue-refresh-token', keycloak.refreshToken)
          }

          // next part to get the new refresh token
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Keycloak initialization error:', error)
          // Handle the initialization error
        })
    },
    logoutWithKeyCloak() {
      keycloak.logout()
      localStorage.removeItem('vue-token')
      localStorage.removeItem('vue-refresh-token')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```